# Expected value (mean) of function from polyline

Tags: probability, geometry, average

Suppose we have a polyline that has such properties:

1. It consists of `n` segments
2. First segment's ends are `(0, 0)` and `(1, 0)`.
3. Every other segment is previous segment rotated by `α` or `-α`

The problem is to find average (of all such polylines) square of distance between start point and end point. How to solve that?

Comment: Are you sure this problem has a (relatively easy) solution? Are you interested in an algorithm or in a formula in terms of $\alpha, n$?

Comment: Well, I'm sure this problem has quite short and not very difficult solution.
I am interested in a formula.

Comment: Do you mean "Every other segment is previous segment rotated by `α` or `-α` then translated so the start of the new segment is the end of the previous segment"?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Is the rotation angle $\alpha$ the same for all segments or different? If the same, then the only varying factor is whether $\alpha$ or $-\alpha$ is chosen for each new segment?

Comment: α is the same for all segments and all polylines

Comment: I am trying brute force with the simple case $\alpha = 90^°$ but I cannot find any pattern.

Comment: One can reformulate the problem using complex numbers, and then write it using some sum notation. But that doesn't help much. The main problem is that a simple recursive description won't work since to know the average distance spanned by a long polyline, you not only need the average distance for a shorter one, but the actual distribution of difference vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to solve this.

Solution:

Let

1. $z = \cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha$
2. $S_{(i_1,...,i_n)}$ = $1 + z^{i_1} + z^{i_1 + i_2} + ... + z^{i_1 + ... + i_n}$
3. $H_n = \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} (S_{(i_1,...,i_n)} + \bar{S}_{(i_1,...,i_n)})$
4. $D_n = \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} |S_{(i_1,...,i_n)}|^2$

What we want to find is $D_n\over{2^n}$.

It is obvious, that $S_{(i_1,...,i_n)}$ = $1 + z^{i_1}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)}.$

So $$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H_n 
&= \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} (S_{(i_1,...,i_n)} + \bar{S}_{(i_1,...,i_n)}) \\ 
&= \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} (1+z^{i_1}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + 1 + \bar{z}^{i_1}\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)}) \\
&= 2^{n+1} + \sum_{(i_2,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}} (zS_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{z}\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{z}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + z\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)}) \\
&= 2^{n+1} + (z+\bar{z})\sum_{(i_2,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}} (S_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)}) \\
&= 2^{n+1} + H_{n-1}2\cos\alpha
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

By induction we can prove, that $H_n = 2^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} cos^k\alpha=2^{n+1}\frac{\cos^{n+1}\alpha - 1}{\cos\alpha - 1}$

Also 
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
D_n
&= \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} |S_{(i_1,...,i_n)}|^2 \\
&= \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} (1+z^{i_1}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)})(1+\bar{z}^{i_1}\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)}) \\
&= \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} (1 + z^{i_1}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{z}^{i_1}\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + |S_{(i_2,...,i_n)}|^2) \\
&= 2^n + 2D_{n-1} + \sum_{(i_1,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n} (z^{i_1}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{z}^{i_1}\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)}) \\
&= 2^n + 2D_{n-1} + \sum_{(i_2,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}} (zS_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{z}\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + \bar{z}S_{(i_2,...,i_n)} + z\bar{S}_{(i_2,...,i_n)}) \\
&= 2^n + 2D_{n-1} + (z+\bar{z})\sum_{(i_2,...,i_n)\in\{-1,1\}^{n-1}} (S_{(i_1,...,i_n)} + \bar{S}_{(i_1,...,i_n)}) \\
&= 2^n + 2D_{n-1} + H_{n-1}2\cos\alpha = 2D_{n-1} + H_n - 2^n
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

By induction we can prove, that $D_n = 2^n\frac{2\cos\alpha(\cos^{n+1}\alpha - 1) - (n+1)(\cos^2\alpha - 1)}{(\cos\alpha - 1)^2}$

So the answer is $\frac{D_n}{2^n} = \frac{2\cos\alpha(\cos^{n+1}\alpha - 1) - (n+1)(\cos^2\alpha - 1)}{(\cos\alpha - 1)^2}$